# how to display image in asp .net using string builder class

Tags: asp.net

I am using string builder class to display an image but the image is not coming

My code is

```
 StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
 sb1.AppendLine("<tr>");
 string url = "<img src='~/images/youtube.png'/>";

sb1.AppendLine("<td style='padding-top:3px;border:solid 1px orange;text-    
align:center'><a href='http://www.linkedin.com/groups/
'><img src=url style='height:55px;width:220px;border-style:solid; padding-
left:50px/></a></td>");
sb1.AppendLine("</tr>");
```

Comment: First of all don't use it like this, it's easy to maintain after a few day or months, i suggest you to use an Object (System.Web.Image)

Comment: please put your .aspx page and where you are using the sb1

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign this html to your page `element`. You need server accessible html element to assign the html to it. You can make a table server accessible by assigning id to it and setting `runat = "server"`.

*In html*

```
<table id="tbl" runat="server" >

</table>
```

*In  Code bahind*

```
tbl.InnerHTML  = sb1.ToString();
```

Comment: have you seen the path of the image it is in double quotes

Comment: I made the table server accessible like you access textbox you can access table and assign html you created to this table.

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem is with in the line

```
 sb1.AppendLine("<td style='padding-top:3px;border:solid 1px orange;text-    
 align:center'><a href='http://www.linkedin.com/groups/QuickMove-Core-Business-Solutions-
 Moving-3791901'><img src=url style='height:55px;width:220px;border-style:solid; padding-
 left:50px/></a></td>");
```

use it like this

```
 sb1.AppendLine("<td style='padding-top:3px;border:solid 1px orange;text-    
 align:center'><a href='http://www.linkedin.com/groups/QuickMove-Core-Business-Solutions-
 Moving-3791901'><img src="+url+" style='height:55px;width:220px;border-style:solid; padding-
 left:50px/></a></td>");
```

---

Edit

change

```
 string url = "<img src='~/images/youtube.png'/>";
```

to

```
string url = "/images/youtube.png";
```

Comment: but in url the image is not displaying. what to do

Comment: check the path of the image after it renders in the browser using view source

Comment: its coming as file:///D:\website\QuickMove Website\images\youtube.png.then how to put as url

Answer (score 0):

This is a much better way, not messing with any of the `strings`, much cleaner.
Server side:

```
        Table tbl = new Table();
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell td = new TableCell();

        td.Controls.Add(new Image
            {
                ImageUrl = "http://www.your-site.com/content/images/pic.jpg"
            });
        tr.Cells.Add(td);
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

        ph.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

aspx page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph" />
```